# Mod Rewrite for .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My URL's currently are like this: `http://www.example.com/?content=contact.php`

But I want the user to have the following in the URL field: `http://www.example.com/contact.php`

I added this to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?content=$1 [L]
```

But I'm getting this error now:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at www.example.com Port 80

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this i am assuming contact.php is not an actual file,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?content=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This opens `http://www.example.com/contact.php` instead of opening `http://www.example.com` and set `content=contact.php`. Do you have an other idea?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?content=$1
```

This rule redirect all the request to index.php and pass as GET the variable 'content'.

For example:

http://www.example.com/contact.php -> ?content = contact.php

http://www.example.com/some/folder/ -> ?content = some/folder/

Comment: This opens `http://www.example.com/contact.php` instead of opening `http://www.example.com` and set `content=contact.php`. Do you have an other idea?

Comment: As you say: 'But I want the user to have the following in the URL field: http://www.example.com/contact.php'

Comment: The problem is if `example.com/contact.php` if opens the file `/contact.php` because it exist but it should open `example.com/` and set GET parameter `content=contact.php` instead.

Comment: You can put all the files in a folder ( ex. 'template/') and from index.php ask for (template/?content). Please note that use a GET variable as path for include a file could lead to Directory Transversal attack from malicious users. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack

Comment: My `index.php` is on `/index.php` and my content-php-file are in `/content/`. What .htaccess do I need now?

Comment: The same, when you go to example.com/contact.php the server redirect you to example.com/ (index.php is implicit if you don't have an index.html in the same folder). So in index.php you have this variable: $_GET['content'] (try to print it out to see the value). From index.php now you can ask to include('content/'.$_GET['content']);

Comment: But I'm still getting `Internal Server Error`. What am I doing wrong?